# how to refresh/reload/update accordion datas with new datas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

could some one tell me, how to update accordion datas with new values on button click as when user enter their input?

assume like there is input box. user hit submit after giving value. at the same time it should show the input what user gives in side accordion.

accordion ll be categorized as

```
/Latest update
/old updates
/etc
```

what am having is

```
$("className").click(function(){ 
setInterval(function(){                 
            }, 900);    
    })
    <div classname="className"></div>
```

it would be better if share fiddle/plunker snippets for Typescript, Jquery or even Angular2

many thanks for any help

Comment: so you want people to answer with ` fiddle/plunker snippets for Typescript, Jquery or even Angular2` but you don't provide a working snippet ? interesting way to ask for help

Comment: @MihaiT blind in idea about from where to start if you're really interested to help beginners in new techs. try to do help. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . please read here. make a working snippet that replicates your problem and show what you have tried so far. SO is not a code making site

Comment: am not asking anyone here to code for me. just ask about if someone has came across this scenario thats it. almost all of the stackoverflow response came up with example plunker or fiddle link. thats wat am looking for okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because i had some free time i made you an example of what i think you want.

1.enter 'aa' the `latest updates` will slideDown and have text 'aa'

2.enter second value 'bb' the `latest updates` will have text 'bb' , `old updates` will have text 'aa' and also 'aa' is archived

3.enter third value 'cc' the `latest updates` will have text 'cc', `old updates` will have text 'bb' and archive will have 'aa' and 'bb'

and so on.

this is made using IF conditions which are very straight forward using `text().length`.

also included ( at the beginning of the JQ ) a simple accordion code

let me know if this is what you were looking for. check snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/xhfh3avp/1/)

```js
var accTrigger = $('h2')
$(".text").hide()
$("h2").on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).siblings(".text")
  if ($(text).is(":visible")) {
    $(text).slideUp()
  } else {
    $(text).slideDown()
  }
  $(this).parents(".accordion-item").siblings().find(".text").slideUp()
});


var button = $("button"),
  input = $("input"),
  latest = $("#latest .text"),
  old = $("#old .text"),
  archive = $("#archive .text")



$(button).on("click", function() {
  inputValue = $(input).val()

  if ($(latest).text().length > 0) {
    $(old).text($(latest).text()).slideDown()

  }
  if ($(old).text().length > 0) {
    var aText = $(archive).html()
    $(archive).html(aText + '<br>' + $(old).text()).slideDown()
  }
  $(latest).text(inputValue).slideDown()


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item" id="latest">
    <h2>Latest Updates</h2>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item" id="old">
    <h2>Old Updates</h2>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item" id="archive">
    <h2>Archive</h2>
    <div class="text"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" value="">
<button type="submit">
  submit value
</button>
```

Comment: and thanks for spending your valuable time for making this. this is wat i looking for thanks alot